# Convert date and time to seconds

Tags: shell, aix

I have to convert the following date into seconds, which is stored in a variable.

```
var_date=2017/02/16.10:09:59
```

I am using AIX, an IBM Unix System and the following command is not working out.

```
date -d $var_date +%s
```

Can any one please suggest a solution to overcome this issue?

Answer (score 1):

There is a requirement of date string format which is passed as an argument of `-d` option:

1. It should consists of DATE and TIME, only DATE or only TIME parts

   ```
   DATE
   TIME
   DATE TIME
   ```
2. DATE and TIME parts are delimitared from each other by space or any literal character [a-zA-Z]:

   ```
   DATE TIME
   DATETTIME
   DATEATIME
   DATEiTIME
   ...
   ```
3. The string can be started from DATE or TIME part:

   ```
   DATE TIME
   TIME DATE
   ```
4. DATE is presented by 2 or 3 parts which are delimitared by '/' or '-' sign:

   ```
   YYYY/MM/DD
   YYYY-MM-DD

   MM/DD
   MM/DD/YYYY
   YYYY/MM/DD
   ```

   Pay attention that MM and DD are mandatory fields and month should be put before day.
   If year is not defined, current year is considered.
   It also allowed to use date without delititars. In this case date can be presented in following format only:

   ```
   YYYYMMDD
   ```
5. TIME contains from 1 to 3 parts which are delimitared by ':' sign:

   ```
   HH
   HH:MM
   HH:MM:SS
   ```

   If there is no DATE part, current date is considered.

Answer (score 0):

Try adding quotes for the variable.
date -d "$var_date" +%s

```
    $ var_date=2017/02/16.10:09:59
    $ date -d "$var_date" +%s
    1487236199
```